# Remote desktop connection over VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2022

I have a Server machine that has both VPN and RDP Enables(Windows Server 2022).

The vpn base is L2TP and users have no problem connecting to the server with it.

Also the RDP port is open so users can connect to machines/login into it.

Now the question is , how can i avoid the user to directly connect to the server with RDP without vpn. Because atm users do not need vpn at all to use RDP.

Also, Is RDP secure without any Tunneling connection like vpn ?

Comment: your question is leaking information. does the server have an public ip? you would simpley need to restrict rdp port 3389 via the WAN interface and allow it via the VPN interface.

Comment: @Flo Yes i have access to server from Internet , and also i can access it with RDP over internet too. As u mentioned , should i apply this restriction via windows defender firewall?

Comment: Depends on how your network is setup. is the server directly connected to the internet? or is it some kind of VM? where is it hosted? windows defender firewall would work though. Be careful in any way, you could lock yourself out.

Answer (score 0):

Internal network RDP can be restricted to specific groups or users, use of VPN is not supported. Use IPSec with NPS if really needed.

External network (e.g. Internet) VPN will be required, VPN allow rule for RDP required, granted that you do not have a public IP mapped to the Server and RDP access is blocked.